# Prevent posting of object if combination of unique fields already exist in a record with Entity Framework (DB First) (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have a an object as follows:

```
var example = new Example
{
    SomeName = viewModel.SomeName,
    SomeTitle = viewModel.SomeTitle,
    SomeAddress = viewModel.SomeAddress,
    SomeCity = viewModel.SomeCity
};

_class.AddObject(example);
```

The AddObject method uses an Add entity method from a repository. The domain upon which the view model is based has been generated by Entity Framework (6), DB first.

I'm currently trying ensure that the example object can not be posted unless it has a unique `SomeName`, `SomeAddress` and `SomeCity`. If a record already exists in the database with the same combination of those three fields, I'll show the user an error message.

Is there a built in way to do this in Entity Framework? Since the domain model has been auto-generated, I know that I can't annotate the properties there. I'm not sure if there's something I can do in the view model, or it's best to write some custom logic.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What about query the database to check if this combination already exists? Is this an option?

Comment: Why not do a `SingleOrDefault` on the `DbSet` with `r => r.SomeCity == someCity...`. Doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa That works, however I'm trying to avoid writing sql in the source code. I'd prefer using Entity since that's the pattern, however since I only recently started using it, I wanted to see if the community might know a better way or even how to do it with Entity.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal Trying this now - thank you.

Comment: here's a link to some documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/

Comment: I don't know if it's an option, but you could create a Compound Key with these fields,  in this case when you `SaveChanges()` an exception would be thrown

Comment: If you decide to query database you can do `bool recordExists = _myContext.MyTable.Any(x => x.SomeName == viewModel.SomeName && x.SomeAddress == viewModel.SomeAddress && x.SomeCity == viewModel.SomeCity)`

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa Thank you! I misunderstood the first time since, but LINQ was the solution. Your answer is the solution that worked for me. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: in the database design set the 3 columns together to be primary keys , so any new duplicated combination will raise an error
....
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,    Addresss varchar(255) NOT NULL, City varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (Name ,Addresss, City  )
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to check if the register already exists in the database prior insert a new record.

To make things easier and don't load anything unwanted in memory you can use `Any()` method along a lambda expression to query the database. This method will return `true` if any record with the provided filter is found or `false` if not.

```
bool recordExists = _myContext.MyTable.Any(x => x.SomeName == viewModel.SomeName && 
                                                x.SomeAddress == viewModel.SomeAddress && 
                                                x.SomeCity == viewModel.SomeCity)
```